# React Visual Studio Code shows red brackets while code is correct

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, ide

This is very simple component I built throughout the course I take (Recently I've started learning React). This "error" only occures when I add a dollar sign inside a `<div></div>` in combination with `{}`. Since the code runs without any errors in the Node.js environment, why is my IDE behaving that strangely? I think there might be something wrong with the settings, but it's only my assumption. Have someone had this issue before or maybe know how to solve it? It's kinda frustrating for me, especially when I'm just learning the framework and the IDE shows mistakes in the places where there are no mistakes.

[image: error image]

Answer (score 1):

I just found a solution. It was Bracket Pair Colorizer 2 extension. After disabling it the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

in my case it was Prettier extension causing these random red colored brackets. Disabling it solved the issue immediately.